# Bigquery/Python: SQL Logic for identifying table direction using a column

Tags: sql, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, google-bigquery

**Input Data:**

```
Store   Aisle   Bay     Angle
11      33      1       0.0
11      33      2       360.0
11      33      3       90.0
11      33      4       180.0
11      33      5       270.0
11      34      1       360.0
11      34      2       90.0
11      34      3       180.0
11      34      4       270.0
12      34      1       89.83
12      34      2       179.83
12      34      3       269.83
12      34      4       269.83
12      34      5       359.83
```

**Scenario:**
Need to frame this logic in either Bigquery SQL Query or using Python for identifying table direction(*Order of direction - Front/Right End/Back/Left End*) using `Angle` Column.

**Conditions:**

1. Stores have angle starting at 0. Need to make a logic for identifying the lowest angle and that becomes the front facing (0 angle)
2. Add 90 degree to this to get the direction of other tables.

**Expected Output:**

```
Store   Aisle   Bay     Angle       Direction
11      33      1       0.0         Front
11      33      2       360.0       Front
11      33      3       90.0        Right End
11      33      4       180.0       Back
11      33      5       270.0       Left End
11      34      1       360.0       Front
11      34      2       90.0        Right End
11      34      3       180.0       Back
11      34      4       270.0       Left End
12      34      1       89.83       Front
12      34      2       179.83      Right End
12      34      3       269.83      Back
12      34      4       269.83      Back
12      34      5       359.83      Left End
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: I can see that the values go from 0 to 89.99 in the front direction then from 90 to 179.9 in the right direction. Is this correct? Also, an angle value can be more than 360? For example if there is an angle value that is 450 this would be a right direction angle, can this happen?

Comment: Actually we shouldn’t declare our directions with angle value(like if it’s within 90 then front or 90 then right) but to take least angle value for a store as front and add 90 to it then declare right direction and so on.. And also as per your example, a store will only have 4 unique angle values, if 450 is one of the angle it should fall within those angle values of the store on adding 90 to least angle value and so as the directions assigned.

Comment: A least angle value of a store can also be greater than 90 like 95 or 250 which will be the Front direction for that store and other directions are defined on adding 90 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *,
  case div(cast(angle - min(if(angle = 360, 0, angle)) over(partition by store, aisle) as int64), 90)
    when 1 then 'Right'
    when 2 then 'Back'
    when 3 then 'Left'
    else 'Front'
  end as direction
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]